# Htaccess to write domainname/index.php?var1=abc?var2=def?var3=ghi to domainname/var1/var2/var3

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need help with htaccess in writing multiple GET variables to domainname/var1/var2/var3 Please help me to write it.

Comment: This isn't much of a question, but posted a response anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your question to reflect what you asked in your title

However, the rule for that particular case would be

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
```

Keep in mind that htaccess won't rewrite the URLs for you, that's up to your app or CMS to do. htaccess just knows how to translate rewritten url to common query strings.

Edit: Ouch, wrong answer. I fixed it now according to your comment.

Comment: when I hit url domain/abc/def/ghi it gives me object not found message. Please help me

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1  This htaccess work when I hit domain/username but it does not work with multiple parameters.

Comment: Fixed. You might still need to write additional rules for different number of parameters

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply, But still it gives object not found.Can you please give me idea on additional rules needed.

Comment: Hey You are correct man, It works. Thanks. Only problem is with the css,js,images . Then I have to give absolute path of them everywhere which solves that problem.

Comment: Yes, if you have relative routes and rewrite some urls to look like a subfolder, Apache will look inside that subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

HtAccess rewriting is basically a modified version of Regular Expressions. Check this link out. It may help you in writing your own.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html